# Filter results by start of word

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, servlet-filters

I am working on a project in a ReactJS course, and have come across a question. I want to search the results and filter based on the BEGINNING of words, not just the string being present anywhere in the result.

For example, in a list of contacts, typing "r" may return **R**ichard, Aa**r**on, and Ba**r**ba**r**a, because they all contain "r". How do I make it so that it filters from the beginning of the word onward, like in a dictionary?

I am currently filtering results from an array using a controlled component to dynamically search and filter results. Here is the relevant snippet as of now:

```
filterResults = (venueFilter) => {
  let filteredVenues = this.state.venues
  filteredVenues = filteredVenues.filter((venue) => {
    let venueData = venue.name.toLowerCase();
    return venueData.indexOf(venueFilter.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  })
  this.setState({
    filteredVenues
  })
}
```

The project is calling restaurants near me. But then typing "r" brings up many things, as it is a common letter and because "restaurant" starts with R. Typing "M" brings up both a Japanese Restaurant "**M**IKADO" (helpful/good UX), but also returns "Sia**m** Thai" and "Stadt**m**auer" (not particularly helpful/bad UX).

What can I do to filter from the beginning of a word?

Comment: `(not particularly helpful/bad UX).`  I'd actually say been able to search this way is good UX, not bad.  Eg.  it's nice to type `Thai` and get `Siam Thai`..  The more you type, the more specific your results become.

Comment: Thanks. I actually agree with you, but narrowing out the middles of words would be helpful. In your example, I get your point. But in cases where it's a random string in the middle of words, it's not as helpful. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead of `indexOf`

```
filteredVenues = filteredVenues.filter(venue =>
  venue.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(venueFilter.toLowerCase())
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to check if a strings match the requirement or not

```js
const data = [
 'MIKADO',
 'Siam Thai',
 'Stadtmauer',
 'Another',
 'Ane',
 'Anna',
];

// What the user typed for it's search
const search = 's';

// Build a regex using the searched string
// i for case insensitive
const regex = new RegExp(`^${search}`, 'i');

const filteredData = data.filter(x => regex.test(x));

console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a regular expression, which can anchor to the start of a word via the `\b` word boundary flag.

```
filteredVenues = filteredVenues.filter((venue) => {
    return new RegExp('/\\b'+venueFilter+'/', 'i').test(venue.name);
})
```

Note how we also don't need to harmonise strings to lowercase, because by using the `i` case-insensitive flag, it'll match for either case.

Sidenote: This is an example of using a 'dynamic' regular expression, one built to factor in variables. This wouldn't have been possible with a REGEX literal, i.e. one created not with the `new RegExp` constructor but just with `/pattern/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial bellow may help you:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

It has that code section on the filtered search that do what you want (i guess).

```
    inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about sorting by the first occurence? Through that, the ones that match at the beginning appear first:

```
 const result = venues
   .map(venue => ({ venue, score: venue.name.indexOf(search) }))
   .filter(it => it.score !== -1)
   .sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score)
   .map(it => it.venue);
```